# mysql дубли превратить в null или пустое поле

Tags: mysql, sql

есть таблица с полями id, date, time
строки

```
1,2016-07-07,11:31:38
2,2016-07-07,11:31:45
3,2016-07-07,11:31:55
5,2016-07-08,10:31:38
6,2016-07-08,12:31:38
```

стандартным запросом `SELECT td.*  FROM  total td`
выводит все, а нужно при дубле даты превратить в null или пустое поле
пример ответа:

```
1,2016-07-07,11:31:38
2,null,11:31:45
3,null,11:31:55
5,2016-07-08,10:31:38
6,null,12:31:38
```

Comment: мне кажется странной идеей делать это через mysql. сделайте в коде после получения ответа, перед выводом (не знаю, куда там оно выводится у вас).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  CASE WHEN T1.id = T2.min_id THEN T1.date ELSE null END AS date,
  time
FROM total T1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id, date FROM total GROUP BY date) AS T2
ON T1.date = T2.date;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2757/5

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT td.id, 
  IF(@prev_date = date, NULL, @prev_date := date)  date, 
  time
FROM  total td, (SELECT @prev_date := NULL)T
ORDER BY id
```

Вторая строчка расшифровывается примерно так:
Если текущая дата равна предыдущей, тогда выводим NULL, иначе выводим текущую дату и запоминаем её как предыдущую для последующей обработки.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2757/6